# xhrFields withCredentials: true does not send cookies

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies, asp.net-ajax

I have a .Net MVC UI that communicates with a web api via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
```

On Web api i have the following custom headers:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value = "origin"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value = "true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value = "X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="origin"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

It Works on localhost, all the cookies and creadentials are sent, but it is not working on the server, the cookies are not sent on the request header. Do i have to do any configuration on IIS or something?

Request Headers on server:

```
GET /Midia/avatar/usuario HTTP/1.1
Host: *link
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: *link*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Response Header on Server:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: origin
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 12:03:51 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The answer is 400 because the webapi answers 400 when it doesnt receive a cookie.

Request header on localhost:

```
GET /midia/avatar/usuario/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53819
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:64853
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: *link*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L0F1dGVudGljYWNhbw2=DtCsXQUKw6eR3KbEcKQYg1X7iiCAvhaa24NtmGkE-r-JhYFNp0R8Zza1tzURfpO5FBQdTlcj7CeQCcLk93Zsg7iw89I1; ASP.NET_SessionId=ulvf0uszdeddlsfs5vapggef; AuthToken=52c4b98b-a75f-4fef-83ec-83bdb786bff6
```

Comment: There must be some sort of difference I guess, yes. But we can't see either of your servers or clients. All we can see are the parts which are the same, not the parts which are different. Also, why are you specifying "crossDomain: true"? This just simulates a crossDomain request even if the request is not really cross-domain (see the jQuery ajax docs). It's not often useful except for certain testing scenarios to simulate a real CORS request, or in rare cases of, say a server-side redirect to another domain. I doubt you need it.

Comment: @ADyson but it is a real cross domain

Comment: exactly, which is why you don't need to simulate one using this option. I don't think it helps you.

Comment: @ADyson ok, i got it. I edited the question and added the headers